# How fast can I pipe data through a TI Delfino in 1.5 KB chunks?

Tags: microcontroller, serial

Say I program a Delfino with this C snippet:

```
int main () {
    while (true) {
        byte packet[1536];
        readPacketFromUSB(packet);
        writePacketToSerial(packet);
    }
}
```

How quickly can I run the loop, copying 1536 bytes from USB to serial?

From [the TMS320F28377S microcontroller datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tms320f28377s.pdf):

> Multichannel Buffered Serial Port (McBSP):
>
> McBSP clock rate, \$CLKG = \frac{CLKSRG}{1+CLKGDV}\$
>
> where CLKSRG source could be LSPCLK, CLKX, or CLKR.

It seems that the fastest available configuration is CLKGDV=1 and LSPCLK=200 MHz.

So \$CLKG = 100 MHz\$ or \$100 Mbps\$ baud rate.

Considering only read/write times, my loop *should* run at \$\frac{100 Mbps}{2*(1536 bytes)} ≈ 4.1 KHz\$.

Does 4.1 KHz sound right? Is there a substantial source of overhead that I'm missing?

Comment: The USB controller only supports 12 MBit Full speed on this chip at the maximum, and there will be some overhead, too.

Comment: In addition to TurboJ's point, where do you get your "2∗(1536bytes)" value from? Your serial UART is sending at least 10 bits per byte, not 2.

Comment: Got it, thanks. Delfino is too slow for my requirements. What are some MCUs that support USB 2.0 "High Speed" (480 Mbit/s) or close to it?